# Pre-Sales Questions

Tags: devdemon, subscriptions

I have a few pre-sales questions about Subscriptions.

1. Can it handle subscribers who pay by cash/cheque? Can they be kept in a Pending group until offline payment confirmed?
2. Can notifications be sent out in advance of a subscription expiring rather than just when expired or renewed? For example, a reminder sent out 4 weeks before the sub expires.
3. Are there any conflicts with other Member addons such as Zoo Visitor?

Very excited by this addon.

Answer (score 2):

1. No it can't do offline payments, we started with Stripe & Authorize.net
2. Is this for non-renewing Subscriptions? Or also for auto-renew?
3. No conflicts, we do want to support member registration and subscription signup on the same form. Would love to hear your set up.

We want to gather as much feedback/ideas as possible. Please get in touch via our contact form so we can keep track of all requests.

We already received some pretty crucial feedback in the last few days.

Comment: What's the current status of PayPal support? The last I can find a few months back was that it was in alpha. Is that to integrate taking cards directly on the site, or even just passing the customer out to PP for payment?

It looks like a promising product, but no PP support makes it a non-starter for many clients.